# Headers not found openfst

Tags: linux, c++11, header, cmusphinx, openfst

I tried to install OpenFst to use it with SphinxTrain and recompile it with g2p enabled, and it seem to work but I got stuck with the following error :

```
checking fst/fstlib.h usability...
no checking fst/fstlib.h presence...
no checking for fst/fstlib.h...
no configure: error: fst/fstlib.h header not found
```

But the OpenFst binaries are well installed in /usr/local/lib/fst and the headers too in /usr/local/include/fst..

Can anyone give me a clue about the issue ?

Comment: I answered you on the forum https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/c58f60cb

Comment: that's right, thank you again very much :) !

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Perhaps, for completeness, you could copy the answer over to here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/help/thread/c58f60cb/:

It looks in `/usr/include` by default, not in `/usr/local/include`. You probably need to set `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` before configure:

```
CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib ./configure ....
```

Overall I do not recommend you to use this feature, it never worked well. Use `phonetisaurus` to extend the dictionary or `g2p-seq2seq`.